# Express server GET request userId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to create an GET API route for taskuser/getallusers?userId='' .

I want to get all tasks that are assigned to a specific user. But when i test this call (http://localhost:4000/api/taskuser/getalltasks?userId=5bfe4af425ddde2b04eb19c6) but no error ?

I still get all tasks assigned to any user. can someone tell me what goes wrong ?

Model taskuser:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const TaskuserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
task_name:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    unique: true,
},
userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
task_category: String,
task_xpreward: Number,
task_completed: Boolean,
task_difficulty: Number, 
task_city : String,
});
```

Api route:

```
router.get('/getalltasks/:userid', cors(),async(req,res) => { // Add /:userid
 var userid = req.params.userid;
 Taskuser.find({ userId: userid}, function(err, tasks) {
  // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. 
  // nothing after res.send(err) will execute

  if (err)
      res.send(err);

  res.json(tasks); // return all tasks that are in JSON format 

 });
});
```

Edit: new api route

Comment: Taskuser.find({ userId: req.params.userId}, func...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the code to :

```
router.get('/getalltasks/:userid', cors(),async(req,res) => { // Add /:userid
var userid = req.params.userid;
Taskuser.find({ userId: userid}, function(err, tasks) {
    // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. 
    // nothing after res.send(err) will execute
    if (err)
        res.send(err);

    res.json(tasks); // return all tasks that are in JSON format 

  });
});
```

Documentation : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Comment: If i implement your solution i get an empty json body back

Comment: Are you sure there are Task where the userId is the same as the one you pass in `GET` parameters ?

Comment: here are the images with the table of my taskuser in mongodb and postman information (https://imgur.com/a/MrX27fa)

Comment: i change the call from : http://localhost:4000/api/taskuser/getalltasks?user_Id=5bfe4859be5749192cec5d38 ==> http://localhost:4000/api/taskuser/getalltasks?userId=5bfe4859be5749192cec5d38  but still no change

Comment: Updated my code (changed `var userid = req.params.userId;` to `var userid = req.params.user_id;`) as it seems that you are using user_id in postman

Comment: What is the name of the `GET` param ? For instance if you have `http://url:4000?userID=543...` then you should retrieve it with `req.params.userid`, notice the lowercase id

Comment: the name of my `GET` param is like it is saved on the mongo database "userId" with capital "I". Therefore i do : `var userid = req.params.userId;`

Comment: You should try `var userid = req.params.userid;`, even though your `GET` param is `userId`. I had the same issue few month ago

Comment: what to put in my get call ? `http://localhost:4000/api/taskuser/getalltasks?userId=` ? or something else

Comment: I slightly updated the code, yes putting `http://localhost:4000/api/taskuser/getalltasks?userId=` in the call should work

Comment: My bad, I didn't look the first line well... Just edited the code, you must specify the param name in the first parameter of `router.get()`

Comment: I have edited the code aswell call is `http://localhost:4000/api/taskuser/getalltasks/userid=` and the error now is a casterror : `"message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"userid=5bfe4859be5749192cec5d38\" at path \"userId\" for model \"Taskuser\"",`

Comment: well one step ahead, `userid=` should not be in the variable, that's weird. If you `console.log(req.params.userid)` you have `userid=[ID]` ?

Comment: fixed solution !! the correct call was `http://localhost:4000/api/taskuser/getalltasks/5bfe4859be5749192cec5d38`

Answer (score 0):

Change your api route file to this:

```
router.get("/getalltasks", cors(), async (req, res) => {
  var userid = req.params.userId;
  Taskuser.find({ userId: userid }, function(err, tasks) {
    var userid = req.params.userId;

    // if there is an error retrieving, send the error.
    // nothing after res.send(err) will execute
    if (err) res.send(err);
    res.json(tasks); // return all tasks that are in JSON format
  });
});
```

Comment: empty json body